# Fetch dependancies from different directory python

Tags: python

I have been working on developing a certain piece of code and now it works just fine.. and needed to be deployed in the production enviornment.
But the code is not production ready yet.. Earlier I had all the files in the same directory and I was calling all the libraries I built to one unit test I wrote.
But now I have been asked to clean them out.
So earlier my directory sturcture was like  (if there was any structure)

```
 .../project_name/allthecode.py
```

So now This is what my new directory structure looks like.

```
.../project_name/bin/unit_test.py
.../project_name/lib/native/all_the_libraries_i_developed.py's   
.../project_name/lib/third/all_the_third_parties_code.py's
```

Now.. how do I call the libraries in native and third to the bin/unit_test.py

Also, I dont want to hardcode this path.. as it will be later deployed in production environment..qa environment..so I am looking somethin glike..

```
at unit_test.py... go up one level (.../project_name)
now go down one level  (..../project_name/lib)
From ths point move down to native and third...
```

So more like a relative search of directory?
How do i get this in python
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hmmm. ok found the answer.

```
#get current working directory
cur_dir = os.getcwd()
#move up one level
os.chdir("..")
new_cur_dir = os.getcwd()
#move down to native
os.chdir("lib")
 os.chdir("native")
```

reference: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a `setup.py` file for each of the libraries:

```
/project_name/lib/native/x/setup.py

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='x',
      version='1.0',
      packages=['x'],
     )
```

and than install it in `develop` mode (`python setup.py develop`, read more [here](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html))

When you do it like this, your can simply `import x` from anywhere, yet any change to the local code will affect the entire environment.

When in production, you can just as easily install your packages (even in `virtualenv`), and nothing changes.

Complex relative import are discouraged.